# Solve the diphantine equation: xy + 114x - 81y = 9245

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

Im not very experienced in this type of maths as I have only solved simple diophantine equations with euclides, so please explain the whole process used to get to the solution.
The exercise which this equation is from included another equation: 1479x + 1207y = 85 ,but I think its not relevant as it said: Solve each of the following diophantine equations.

Comment: Note that $1479x+1207y=85$ can (and should) be divided by $17$.

Comment: Alpertron has a tool solving diophantine equations with two variables and degree $2$. This type is explicitely explained.